# How to restart the openssl OCSP server automatically

Tags: openssl, ocsp

I run the openssl OCSP server and after I update the index.txt file It can not detect untill I stop the server and restart again. How can I come up with this problem. If there any configuration in openssl side to resolove this.
This is my openssl OCSP server run command.

```
openssl ocsp -port 2560 -text -index 'intermediate/index.txt' -CA 'intermediate/certs/ca-chain.cert.pem -rkey 'ocsp/private/ocsp.key.pem' -rsigner 'ocsp/certs/ocsp.cert.pem' -nmin 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use openssl 3:

-multi process-count

Run the specified number of OCSP responder child processes, with the parent process respawning child processes as needed. **Child processes will detect changes in the CA index file and automatically reload it**. When running as a responder -timeout option is recommended to limit the time each child is willing to wait for the client's OCSP response. This option is available on POSIX systems (that support the fork() and other required unix system-calls).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).